# Pythonic way to enforce order in which methods must be called

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class House:

    def __init__(self, estimated_cost):
        # let's say states are planning, building, built and sold
        self.state = "planning"
        self.estimated_cost = estimated_cost

    def hire_contractors():
        # HIRE SOME CONTRACTORS
        if self.state not in ("planning", "contractors_hired"):
            raise ValueError("We cannot hire contracts if the house is not in planning or building phase!")
        self.state = "contractors_hired"

    def build_house():
        # do stuff to build the house, NEED CONTRACTORS
        if self.state != "contractors_hired":
            raise ValueError("We cannot build a house without having contractors!")
        self.state = "built"

    def sell_house():
        # sell house for 10% more than cost estimate
        if self.state != "built":
            raise ValueError("Need to be built before selling!")
        print("Selling house for," self.estimated_cost*1.1)
```

where the following rules are enforced:

- You can hire contracts as long as you are in the `planning` or `contractors_hired` state
- You can build a house if you are in the `contractors_hired` state
- You can sell the house if you are in the `built` state.

Otherwise errors are raised. Apologies if this is confusing I can add an example with a, b, c later.
The current method "works" but seems unpythonic. Are there any better ways of having a state that allows certain methods to be called? This only needs to be enforced through error raising and/or warnings.

EDIT: I realize things are confusing, in reality I'm building an ML model which has something similar to:

```
class Model:

    def set_hyperparams():
        # Can be done always

    def train():
        # Can only be done once set_hyperparams

    def predict():
        # Can only be done once trained
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is a sensible design for a class. This `House` class doesn't represent a house. It doesn't really represent anything.

Comment: What do you mean by unpythonic? You are not using any external library.

Comment: You could use decorators to ensure certain properties when the methods are called.

Comment: The class would have to enforce the order itself (internally) somehow because there is no way to control what external software might do. You might be able to implement what you want via a statemachine which would have a very limited generic interface consist of only one method that could be called to have it change state internal and perform the process equivalent to one of the method you have.

Comment: The code looks pretty much like what you described you wanted: each method performing its main purpose only at certain states. As for doing things in *order*, the thing for that is an iterator, which moves to the next item when iterated (look up a tutorial on `__next__`, `__iter__`, for-loops). You could conceivably create a class that implements `__next__` to go through the phases of your home construction, and use a handy `current_phase` method to indicate the current phase.

Comment: The Pythonic and in fact generally sensible thing is *not to do that*. An instance should *always* be in a consistent state that allows all operations defined by the class. What you are looking at are different house types, e.g. a ``PlannedHouse`` which allows to ``build_house`` to get a ``BuiltHouse`` which allows to ``sell_house``. A state machine might be appropriate if you want to merge all that into a single thing – that is expressly not a ``House``, though.

Comment: Interesting @MisterMiyagi. Tbh I chose a confusing example, I am building an ML model which for example can't predict before being trained.

Comment: See Wikipedia article about [Finite State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use decorators to make your code prettier.
The requireState decorator takes a list of required states and checks if one of them is satisfied.

```
def requiresState(*states):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.state in states:
                raise ValueError("Requirements not satisfied")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator    

class House:
    def __init__(self, estimated_cost):
        # let's say states are planning, building, built and sold
        self.state = "planning"
        self.estimated_cost = estimated_cost

    @requiresState("planning", "contractors_hired")
    def hire_contractors(self):
        # HIRE SOME CONTRACTORS
        self.state = "contractors_hired"
    
    @requiresState("contractors_hired")
    def build_house(self):
        # do stuff to build the house, NEED CONTRACTORS
        self.state = "built"
    
    @requiresState("built")
    def sell_house(self):
        # sell house for 10% more than cost estimate
        print("Selling house for,", self.estimated_cost*1.1)
```

Comment: Clever idea. You could simplify it slightly by using `def requiresState(*states):` which would automatically treat all the arguments passed as sequence so that use of the decorator would not require putting them all into one manually.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything *un-pythonic* in what you've got there...

The only design choice I'd recommend is to avoid using an enum `state` member that will inevitably fail to represent all possible states a house can be in... but instead use conditions on members of the class:

```
class House():

    def __init__(self, funds=0, contractors=0):
        self.contractors = contractors
        self.funds = funds

    def add_funds(self, funds):
        self.funds += funds

    def hire_contractor(self, cost):
        if self.funds < cost:
            print(f"{self.funds} not sufficient; funds needed: {cost}")
            return
        self.funds -= cost
        self.contractors += 1

    def hire_contractors(self, *costs):
        for cost in costs:
            self.hire_contractor(cost)

    def build(self, required_contractors=1):
        if self.contractors < required_contractors:
            print(f"please hire more contractors ({self.contractors} available)")
            return
        self.contractors -= required_contractors
```